# How to prevent navigation buttons in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How to disable navigation buttons on the flutter app so the user can't be redirect to another page, recent view, and home.

Using  `onWillPop: () async => false,` only affects the back button.

Comment: you can set logic on it's index

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: show me your code

Comment: @AR I wrapped the WillPopScope around the scaffold, that's all. But I need this functionality. How can that be done in a sample app.

Comment: Please add your code here

Answer (score 0):

Specify `null` for the values of `onTap`, `onPressed`, etc to disable the buttons.

```
onTap: (someCondition) ? null : () {...}
```